# While updating a .txt files contents, it creates a duplicate file with a '?"

Tags: python, file, file-handling

I'm trying to make a file that keeps a players money in it, but while trying to update the line with money on it. It'll create a new file with the same name but with a '?' on the end.

```
Name = input("Username: ")
f = open((Name) + ".txt", "w")
global Money
Money = int(100)
lines = [(Name) + "\n", str(Money)]
f.writelines(lines)
f.close()
```

This is where the file is originally made

```
save = input("What is the file you'd like to refer to?")
f = open((save) + ".txt", "r")
Name = (f.readline())
Money = int(f.readline())
```

This snippet works fine, and it's setting the variables to the data I want as expected. (In another instance)

```
lines = [(Name) + "\n", str(Money)]
```

I've defined 'lines' as these lines here in a previous module.

```
global Name
Money = Money - 50
f = open((Name) + ".txt", "w")
f.writelines(lines)
f.close()
```

This is the snippet that creates another file, I just want it to update the file but instead it's creating another. (Sometimes it doesn't do anything at all)

Comment: There is no need for `global` here. I can only assume that you have this in a function and you're getting the textbook thrown at you on why `global`s are a bad idea. Please give a [mcve] to recreate the problem.

Comment: why all those parentheses?

Comment: The reason i haven't given you the full code and I've just done the part that going wrong. is its currently 323 lines away from where the variables are defined.

Comment: What do you get if you `print(Name + '.txt')` before you write to the file?

Comment: After i've originally made the file for the first time it gives me mansand.txt (mansand is the eg name) however when im trying to rewrite it gives me mansand (then a new line) .txt

Comment: When you read `Name` from the file, there's a trailing newline that you need to strip - `Name = f.readline().rstrip('\n')`

Comment: Thanks a lot snake! .rstrip fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the filename contains a newline character (`'\n'`). The `ls` utility will replace this character with a question mark when displaying the filename.

The newline comes from this code:

```
save = input("What is the file you'd like to refer to?")
f = open((save) + ".txt", "r")
Name = (f.readline())
Money = int(f.readline())
```

The line returned by `f.readline` includes the newline at the end of the line.

The easiest way to remove the newline is to use [str.rstrip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip), like this:

```
Name = f.readline().rstrip('\n')
```

This would also work:

```
Name = f.readline().rstrip()
```

if `rstrip` isn't passed a parameter it will remove *all* trailing whitespace characters.

The "Money" line in the file does not have a trailing newline, but it might be prudent to call `rstrip` on it regardless, as one could potentially be added if the file is edited in a text editor, or if more lines were added to the file.

In the bash shell you can "see" the newlines by piping the output of `ls` through `cat` or `sed` (credit to [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/361432/question-marks-in-filenames-and-samba#comment640499_361432)):

```
>  ls test*.txt
test?.txt
>  ls test*.txt | cat
test
.txt
>  ls test*.txt | sed -n l
test$
.txt$
```